# Azure Website Kudu HTMLLog Analysis shows Always On with high response time

Tags: performance, azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu, alwayson

We deployed our WebAPI as an azure website under the standard plan and have turned on Always On. After getting multiple memory and CPU alerts we decided on checking the logs via xyz.scm.azurewebsites.net. It seems Always ON has a high response time. Could this be causing high memory and CPU issues. Sometimes the alerts come when none is even using the system and auto resolve within 5 mins.

[image]

Comment: You could try to troubleshoot slow web app performance 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation.

Answer (score 0):

The always on feature **only invokes the root of your web app every 5 minutes**.

If this is causing high memory or cpu it could be a memory leak within your application because if you don't use the always on feature your process gets recycled on idle.

You should check what your app does if you invoke it with the root path and determine why this is causing high response time.

Comment: The root path has been configured to simply return a 200 OK response.

Comment: I have also noticed that inspite of enabling always on, the root path takes much more time on the first hit and then its faster on subsequent hits...as if the always on is not working..

Comment: @Anshulee  Maybe it takes time to create the controller? However, as far as I know the always on feature only invokes your app every 5 minute, you could do the same by yourself. So to find out why you are getting high response time or memory usage you have to check your app